# Проблемы с чтением значений из памяти с использованием memory.dll в C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

Я новичок в программировании на C# и столкнулся с проблемой, в решении которой, надеюсь, опытные программисты смогут мне помочь.

У меня возникла проблема: при попытке чтения значений из памяти в консоли ничего не отображается. Я использую библиотеку memory.dll и уверен, что адреса и указатели правильные, так как при перезапуске приложения через Cheat Engine значения находятся без проблем. Однако, по какой-то причине, я не могу считать эти значения непосредственно из кода.

У кого-нибудь есть идеи, почему это происходит и как мне получить доступ к этим значениям? Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь или руководство!

Заранее спасибо

```
using Memory;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
 
namespace code
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Mem m = new Mem();
            bool ProcOpen = false;
            int name = m.GetProcIdFromName("cslauncher");
            Console.WriteLine("Id proc: {0}", name);
 
            ProcOpen = m.OpenProcess(name);
            Console.WriteLine(ProcOpen);
            while (true)
            {
                string coins = m.ReadMemory<string>("hw.dll+007BBD9C,90");
                Console.WriteLine("This is your situation now: " + coins);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
 
            Console.ReadKey();
 
        }
    }
}
```